# Python-Pandas- Calculation of days using datetime columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format

I have  2 columns  , createddate, closeddate and need to create a new column where closeddate minus createddate and if closed date is null then  impute it with sysdate.

The closed date and created date is datetime64[ns] dataype.
Below is the sample dataframe

```
``df:

    createddate                      closeddate   
     30-06-2023  6.21.58 PM           03-07-2023  5.29.44 PM
     30-06-2023  6.18.16 PM

                            

Expected output

createddate                      closeddate                     Ageing_days
 30-06-2023  6.21.58 PM           03-07-2023  5.29.44 PM         3 
 30-06-2023  6.18.16 PM                                          18
```

I tried using below code , but the issue is for the first row using below code it is taking as 2days instead of 3

```
Tried code:

df['aging_cal'] = (df['ClosedDate'].fillna(datetime.datetime.now()) - df['Created']).dt.days
```

Incorrect o/p

```
Expected output

createddate                      closeddate                     Ageing_days
 30-06-2023  6.21.58 PM           03-07-2023  5.29.44 PM         2 
 30-06-2023  6.18.16 PM                                          18
```

Not sure what is wrong in the above code.

Comment: please provide the output of `df.to_dict()` as [edit] to your question, your input is currently ambiguous

Comment: Created column :{0: Timestamp('2023-06-30 18:21:58'),
  1: Timestamp('2023-06-30 18:18:16')}      Closed column :{0: Timestamp('2023-07-03 5:29:44'),
 1: NaT}   ..

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to first `ceil` your Timedelta to the day:

```
df['aging_cal'] = (df['ClosedDate'].fillna(pd.Timestamp('now'))
                 - df['Created']).dt.ceil('D').dt.days
```

Output:

```
              Created          ClosedDate  aging_cal
0 2023-06-30 18:21:58 2023-07-03 05:29:44          3
1 2023-06-30 18:18:16                 NaT         18
```

Reproducible input:

```
from pandas import Timestamp, NaT

df = pd.DataFrame({'Created': {0: Timestamp('2023-06-30 18:21:58'),
                               1: Timestamp('2023-06-30 18:18:16')},
                   'ClosedDate': {0: Timestamp('2023-07-03 5:29:44'),
                                  1: NaT}})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cound diff disregarding the HH:MM:SS part of the datetime, then you can convert timestamps to date before subtracting:

```
(df['ClosedDate'].fillna(datetime.now()).apply(pd.Timestamp.date) - 
     df['Created'].apply(pd.Timestamp.date)).dt.days
```

Output:

```
0     3
1    18
dtype: int64
```